# Custom sort for my struct

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct `MyType` that contain

```
int a; 
int b;
```

and I have a vector of that type `my_vec`

I need to do a custom sort to sort the vector according to `a`

what's the best way to do that?

Comment: trying to past your code here. you can also use any standard sorting with little modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), [](const MyType& t1, const MyType& t2) { return t1->a< t2->a; });
```

Comment: so please accept my answer as a correct one.